# How to quick search files in whole workspace (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, symfony-4.2

I have used ctrl+p to search my file in whole project but its not working. I am seaching 'Request.php' file which is used to get request. but I am unable to find this using 'ctrl+p'.

Although, ctrl+p finds my controllers and other stuff but it does not search files which are deep down in directory like :

> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request.php.

**Is there ant short key to find these kind of files?**

Answer (score 7):

Go to VS Code Editor:

**File-> Preferences-> Settings**

User Settings file will be open.

Now, **search key 'search.useIgnoreFiles' and set its value to 'False' by clicking on 'pencil icon'.**

Now, Ctrl+p will search all files.

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode, you can go to **File > Preferences > Settings** and search for the setting **Use ignore files** and clear the checkbox. This will enable VSCode to search for files in Vendor directory too.